# using C# how to execute view

Tags: c#

Please helpme how can  i execute View from C#

```
 var emp = new List<Employee>();
                using (SqlConnection con = abs.Getconnection())
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("viewEmployee",con);
                   cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataReader rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if(rdr.HasRows==true){
                        while(rdr.Read()){
                        Employee employee=new Employee();
                            employee.EmpName=rdr["EmpName"].ToString();        
                            emp.Add(employee);
```

Here im Getting Error as This is view object.

Comment: You will need to provide wider context. A [mcve] is required. Also, don't just say you are getting an error - describe explicitly the problem.

Comment: He did post the error. It was `This is view object`.

Comment: No reason for down votes here. It is a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change this line

```
 SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("viewEmployee",con)
```

to this

```
 SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from viewEmployee",con)
```

View is like a table, so you have to select rows from it like you do from table.